# Getting error while connecting to Cassandra in mule

Tags: database, cassandra, mule, connector, anypoint-studio

details : Mule 3.8, CassendraDB downloaded from mulesoft exchange, Cassandra version 3.x, port no : 9042.

The Following error occurs when I test connection in cassandra connector configuration.

Error : org.mule.api.ConnectionException: Read a negative frame size (-2147483648)! at com.mulesoft.mule.cassandradb.CassandraDBConnector.connect(CassandraDBConnector.java:101) at com.mulesoft.mule.cassandradb.connectivity.CassandraDBConnectorConnectionFactory.makeObject(CassandraDBConnectorConnectionFactory.java:52) at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1220) at com.mulesoft.mule.cassandradb.connectivity.CassandraDBConnectorConnectionManager.acquireConnection(CassandraDBConnectorConnectionManager.java:269) at com.mulesoft.mule.cassandradb.connectivity.CassandraDBConnectorConnectionManager.test(CassandraDBConnectorConnectionManager.java:351) at org.mule.tooling.metadata.api.utils.ConnectionTester.internalTestConnection(ConnectionTester.java:88) at org.mule.tooling.metadata.api.utils.ConnectionTester.testConnectionFor(ConnectionTester.java:113) at org.mule.tooling.messageflow.action.TestConnectorConnectionFromMuleConfigAction$1$1$1$1.call(TestConnectorConnectionFromMuleConfigAction.java:68) at org.mule.tooling.messageflow.action.TestConnectorConnectionFromMuleConfigAction$1$1$1$1.call(TestConnectorConnectionFromMuleConfigAction.java:1) at org.mule.tooling.utils.SilentRunner.run(SilentRunner.java:25) at org.mule.tooling.core.StudioDesignContextRunner.runSilentWithMuleProject(StudioDesignContextRunner.java:17) at org.mule.tooling.core.StudioDesignContextRunner.runSilentWithMuleProject(StudioDesignContextRunner.java:37) at org.mule.tooling.messageflow.action.TestConnectorConnectionFromMuleConfigAction$1$1$1.run(TestConnectorConnectionFromMuleConfigAction.java:65) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: org.mule.api.ConnectionException: Read a negative frame size (-2147483648)! at com.mulesoft.mule.cassandradb.CassandraDBUtils.getClient(CassandraDBUtils.java:90) at com.mulesoft.mule.cassandradb.CassandraDBConnector.connect(CassandraDBConnector.java:94) ... 13 more

How can I resolve this error ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of potential config changes that you can try.

Check the following in the cassandra.yaml

authenticator: org.apache.cassandra.auth.PasswordAuthenticator
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0

... and consequently ...

broadcast_rpc_address: NOT 0.0.0.0 eg 1.2.3.4

start_rpc: to true

This is because the MuleSoft cassandraDB connector uses apache thrift and not a native connection. You will also need to set the host and Port in the connection settings in studio to be 0.0.0.0 and 9160 respectively. Trst with a blank username/password pair and it should show a correct connection.

Comment: Yes, Thank You. It is getting connected with thrift server.
but while executing simple query now it shows error 'CQL2 has been removed in Cassandra 3.0. Please use CQL3 instead'.

Comment: yeah, unfortunately, it looks like Cassandra 3.0 won't be supported until the next release of Mule. Sorry about that.